# Call to create Socket just hangs and doesn't connect

Tags: android

I have a simple app in Android and Kotlin that connects to a socket. I have added the following permissions to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I have a singleton object that connects to a `Socket`. Here's the code I have for the `init`:

```
init {
    println("inside init")
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    Thread(Runnable {
        println("about to connect")
        socket = Socket()
        println("connected")
        latch.countDown()
    }).start()
    latch.await()
}
```

The output of the following is:

```
I/System.out: inside init
I/System.out: tid = 356
    about to connect
```

For some reason, it doesn't even want to create the `Socket`. It just gets stuck on that call and does nothing. I am testing this on the emulator.

Any idea?

Comment: It's a bit strange; the generic `Socket` constructor shouldn't block (or throw, here). But that's not the constructor you want, anyway. Where, exactly, do you expect this `Socket` to connect to? You should pass that address into the constructor.

Comment: @greeble31 I messed around a little and found strange behavior. The same code but in my Activity works. It seems like any sort of locking mechanism, whether it is a CountdownLatch, a mutex, or joining a thread, messes up a connection request inside the init method if the init method is called from the main thread.

Comment: I can't imagine what. I'm not a kotlin expert, so maybe it is some sort of kotlin feature. Anyway, you ought to be able to break into the debugger and determine where both threads are stuck.

Comment: @greeble31 Basically, if I make a join or wait or lock in init, the connection call will just hang. If I make a separate method that I manually call after init outside the class, then I don't have any issues. Anyways, I found a workaround, but this is some strange kotlin behavior that might be problematic to some people in the future.